# How do I load more posts using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, dom

I have the following code to load the first 10 blog posts and want to see how I can add a 'more...' text link at the end of the lists to load more posts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    url = 'http://hopexxx.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function(data){
            var postlist = data.responseData.feed.entries;
            var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var entry = postlist[i];
                html += '<li>';
                html += '<a href="#">';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.title + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.author + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.publishedDate + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</div>';
                html += '</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            }
            html += '</ul>';
            $("#postlist").append(html);
           $("#postlist ul[data-role=listview]").listview();

        }});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The google feed API doesn't have the option to skip elements, its just a feed, so it loads all elements (as you already have defined num=... you already know that you can load more than 4 elements (which is the default).

To do what you want you would have to call the same request on button click and then implement some logic to compare if the new result contains elements which are not displayed on your page. If so, simply append them...

Comment: why should he request the posts each time? why not once at the beginning and store it in some global var and do whatever he needs afterwards.

Comment: Read the question, he wants to retrieve 10 and on click on a button, he wants to load more...